# Take down firewall for interface on Centos 7

Tags: networking, centos, firewall, nfs

I am exporting a few items over NFS, but my clients can't mount them. When I try to `showmount -e myServer` I get

```
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 113 (No route to host)
```

A bit of digging shows that this could be due to my firewall. Indeed, `firewall-cmd --list-all` shows:

```
public (default, active)
  interfaces: enp0s25 enp3s0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Now, it is only on the `enp3s0` interface that I want to have these connections on, and I know this is an internal network. As such, I think I can completely take down the firewall on this interface, but I have two questions:

(1) Is this correct? Can I completely take down the firewall for this interface to fix the NFS mounting issue on this internal network?
(2) How would I take down the firewall for *only* this interface so that it stays persistent between reboots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to firewalld [manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7)

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --change-interface=enp3s0
```

must allow all connections on interface.